# Why won't hotkeys work on certain desktop applications?

Tags: autoit, hotkeys

Ok so I have used Autoit, python, and Powertoys to create shortcuts but when I try to use the hotkey on a certain desktop application (Its a cash register app) it will not respond, the script is still working because I go back to notepad and the hot key still works. Does anyone know why the app will not respond to simulated keystrokes?

```
HotKeySet ( '{Insert}' ,'Func1')
HotKeySet ( 'x' ,'Func2')

While 1
    Sleep(50)
WEnd

Func Func1()
    Send("b")
EndFunc


Func Func2()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

The hot key works fine on notepad and the internet but I when I click the Cash Register Application the Hot keys do not work, the script is still running because if I go back to notepad the hotkeys still work.

Comment: Can you share the code? Does the application use that hotkey itself?

Comment: You may be able to use `GUISetAccelerators` it sets hotkeys specifically when a GUI is active. You would set the handle to the cash register app. Just to test if you can use hotkeys within another application, otherwise I am under the impression that hotkeys are being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

What I would start off by doing is checking if the hot key is set or blocked by the existing application. Always check for error.

```
Func Func1()
    If @HotKeyPressed = 0 Then Return MsgBox(0, "Hotkeyset Error", "Hotkey " & @HotKeyPressed & " already set by another task.")
EndFunc
```